# Finding all possible combinations

Tags: combinatorics

7 Friends are at a party.

They decide to play chess. One friend just wants to watch and sets up 3 boards. How many different ways can they be watched?

Now the problem I have in the question is the wording. How would one determine whether the order matters. If the same 2 people move from one board to another would it be counted as a different way of viewing. How about if the same 2 people just switched sides?

Would this be a matter of opinion since the question is not specific enough or am I over-complicating it?

I believe the answer would be $\frac{(6)(5)}{2} = 15$. In that case order does not matter.

Comment: Ummmm.... So, Black and White are not different

Comment: Just to clarify, 15 is not the answer. That is what I believe the answer should be. I don't actually have an answer for the question.

Comment: I think 15 would be the total number of combinations you could have in terms of just one match picking from the 6 people. See my answer below.

Comment: I would guess that the colors matter but the boards don't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors don't matter and boards don't matter:

$$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{2}=90$$

Colors don't matter and boards matter:

$$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{2}\cdot3!=540$$

Colors matter and boards don't matter:

$$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{2}\cdot2^3=720$$

Colors matter and boards matter:

$$\binom{6}{2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{2}\cdot3!\cdot2^3=4320$$

Comment: Can you explain the $3!$ and/or point out where my answer (which contradicts yours) is incorrect?

Comment: @Shane: Your answer doesn't contradict mine. $3!$ is for the case where the boards are different (for example, imagine a red board, a green board and a blue board). You simply did not refer to that case in your answer.

Comment: Oh yes - very true. Thanks.

Comment: @Shane: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the wording is very ambiguous. If it doesn't matter which side of the table they are on or what table they are on, wouldn't there be 90 possible combinations because it's equivalent to picking a first pairing (6 choose 2) then a second (4 choose 2)?
$$ {6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} = 90 \text{ combinations.}$$
If the colors matter, you can just multiple this by $2^3=8$, because that's all the possible color combinations over the three tables. Therefore, if colors matter, there should be
$$ {6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^3 = 720 \text{ combinations.}$$
Finally, if you consider that which friend sits out is also a choice, then you would just multiply this by $7$ to get
$$ {6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^3 \cdot 7 = 5400\text{ combinations.}$$

Comment: Obviously once you've picked a first and a second pairing, only one possible third pairing remains. So you could multiply by $ 2 \choose 2$ also, but that just equals one.

Answer (score 1):

If the spectator is fixed, just treat as if there are only 6 friends.

Considerations that you must make:

Is playing Black/White different?

Is a match between friend A and friend B on the first or the second table different?